# P4V / Helix -- Missing "Checkout and Open" for unsynced files

Tags: perforce, p4v

Before reinstalling P4V, I could right-click a file and go to `Checkout and Open` -- this would auto-sync the file, check it out and open it. Now however, I have to `Get Latest Version` before I have the option to `Checkout and Open` -- can I change this back to how it was somehow?

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior. Perhaps check to see if your Preferences changed. Edit-->Preferences-->Behavior and see if "Prompt to get latest revision..." is no longer selected?

Comment: It wasn't selected, but selecting it didn't change the behavior. I still don't see a `Checkout and Open` option for files that are at revision 0

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I didn't realize it was for revision 0, but I just tried it and it gives me the option, syncs to latest and opens the file. FWIW, I'm on revision 2017.2/1518788 and  using Windows.